# ComboBox OnClick VBA code causing Compile Error (Access)

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

When the VBA code in my OnClick event of the ComboBox is run I get the following error: `"Compile error: Method or data member not found"`

The code in this event is:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblParts (P_Number,PName,Color,Weight,City) VALUES ('" & Me.pNum & "','" & Me.PName & "', '" & Me.clr & "', '" & Me.wt & "', '" & Me.cbocty & "')"
```

If I run the code with the "Me.cbocty" removed it compiles. Can someone please explain what is wrong here.

Comment: Do you have a control named `cbocty`? Check for typo's!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from the code provided the problem seems to be that the VBA code cannot find a control called `cbocty` and therefore `Me.cbocty`doesn't compile causing the error.

To fix this you need to check that the name of your "parts city" combobox matches up with the reference in the VBA code. If they are different pick change the VBA code to the combobox name.